# Visual Studio 2015, 2 new sections(in .exe), same project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

When converting and compiling very simple c++ project from VS2013 to VS2015 i get two new sections in .exe file - according to CFFExplorer - **Debug** and **TLS**.
I checked all the project settings and they are the same in VS2015 as they were in the VS2013. As the result a .exe file got little heavier in size. It's in  release mode ofc.

**The question is: what causes VS2015 and VS2017 (settings, etc...?) to add additional sections (directories) to .exe?**

[image]

**EDIT:** Answer to first part is **/NOCOFFGRPINFO** linker's command line option (to get rid of **Debug** directory)

Comment: TLS is used for various purposes, especially if you link the C++ runtime statically etc. You could sift through the available parts of the runtime sources and I'd also recommend to create a full map file to see what stuff in your final binary correlates to what symbol.