# DLL Debug Information

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have created a production build of a DLL. While scanning it using virustotal, I noticed the result reporting debug information is in the file, as indicated below. Can someone please tell me what is this debug information and how do I remove it ? The DLL is from c++ built using Visual Studio Community 2017.

Before anyone gives me a generic advise that it's good practice to have debug information, I would like to say that no I don't need debug information nor do I wish anyone else to get this debug information.

[image]

DUMPBIN /header for the DLL is the following:

```
PE signature found

File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               5 number of sections
        58FBCD28 time date stamp Sat Apr 22 22:37:44 2017
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
            2102 characteristics
                   Executable
                   32 bit word machine
                   DLL

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             10B magic # (PE32)
           14.10 linker version
           10800 size of code
            9800 size of initialized data
               0 size of uninitialized data
            2E64 entry point (10002E64)
            1000 base of code
           12000 base of data
        10000000 image base (10000000 to 1001DFFF)
            1000 section alignment
             200 file alignment
            6.00 operating system version
            0.00 image version
            6.00 subsystem version
               0 Win32 version
           1E000 size of image
             400 size of headers
               0 checksum
               2 subsystem (Windows GUI)
             140 DLL characteristics
                   Dynamic base
                   NX compatible
          100000 size of stack reserve
            1000 size of stack commit
          100000 size of heap reserve
            1000 size of heap commit
               0 loader flags
              10 number of directories
           17E40 [     14C] RVA [size] of Export Directory
           17F8C [      50] RVA [size] of Import Directory
           1B000 [     1E0] RVA [size] of Resource Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Exception Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Certificates Directory
           1C000 [    11CC] RVA [size] of Base Relocation Directory
           17780 [      38] RVA [size] of Debug Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Architecture Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Global Pointer Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Thread Storage Directory
           177B8 [      40] RVA [size] of Load Configuration Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Bound Import Directory
           12000 [     188] RVA [size] of Import Address Table Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Delay Import Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of COM Descriptor Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Reserved Directory


SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
   1069A virtual size
    1000 virtual address (10001000 to 10011699)
   10800 size of raw data
     400 file pointer to raw data (00000400 to 00010BFF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read

SECTION HEADER #2
  .rdata name
    6834 virtual size
   12000 virtual address (10012000 to 10018833)
    6A00 size of raw data
   10C00 file pointer to raw data (00010C00 to 000175FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Only

  Debug Directories

        Time Type        Size      RVA  Pointer
    -------- ------- -------- -------- --------
    58FBCD28 coffgrp      264 0001782C    1642C    4C544347 (LTCG)
    58FBCD28 iltcg          0 00000000        0

SECTION HEADER #3
   .data name
    1884 virtual size
   19000 virtual address (10019000 to 1001A883)
     800 size of raw data
   17600 file pointer to raw data (00017600 to 00017DFF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
C0000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Write

SECTION HEADER #4
   .rsrc name
     1E0 virtual size
   1B000 virtual address (1001B000 to 1001B1DF)
     200 size of raw data
   17E00 file pointer to raw data (00017E00 to 00017FFF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Only

SECTION HEADER #5
  .reloc name
    11CC virtual size
   1C000 virtual address (1001C000 to 1001D1CB)
    1200 size of raw data
   18000 file pointer to raw data (00018000 to 000191FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
42000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Discardable
         Read Only

  Summary

        2000 .data
        7000 .rdata
        2000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       11000 .text
```

Comment: The debug directory in the .rdata section of the file is getting used for info that doesn't have anything to do with debugging.  Microsoft can't really modify the data directory anymore without breaking a lot of tooling, so this is the workaround.  Profile-guided optimization info is it for example, looks like what this is, the sizes are about right.  It is otherwise always a good idea to include it, you'll need it when you get a minidump back when your program crashed in production.  It does not disclose anything sensitive so not much point in fretting about it.  Dumpbin.exe /headers to see.

Comment: Debug information is typically stored in separate .pdb file, not in executable itself. In your case executable probably has debug section (which you an explore using something like Explorer's suite) not a debug information.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I have added the DUMPBIN output above. Let's say I still want to get rid of the 'debug' information, is it possible ? Firstly, I have no idea about dumps. If someone send me a dump, I wouldn't know what to do with it, and I don't have time or inclination to to learn it . Secondly, my code rarely crash - it's just a personal preference, so the chance of getting a dump back is remote. I have no need for dumping and debugging at all, hence I want to remove all traces of debugging and extraneous information to increase the fun for the romanian and polish script kiddies.

Comment: It is what I guessed, LTCG == Link Time Code Generation.  The feature required to implement PGO.  I could research how to turn it off but no doubt an Eastern European hacker knows this off the top of his head.

Comment: @Hans Passant: well, i hope you will turn up something. The stuff you say sounds like a foreign language to me. So I will leave it in your expert hands. Hopefully, it's a VS option i can turn off. Actually, it not just the script kiddies get excited on debugging and dumping, Microsoft too. They'd jump up and down with joy if they get a dump. It seems everyone is getting a benefit from this debug info except me. It's unfair.

Answer (score 6):

To eliminate the debug directory completely add `/NOCOFFGRPINFO` to the linker command line and turn off Link Time Code Generation under Linker/Optimization (i.e. drop `/LTCG`), which is enabled by default for Release builds in VS2017.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I asked similar q some time ago but with no luck. May be you can also give a clue about TLS directory as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690723/visual-studio-2015-2-new-sectionsin-exe-same-project